# 2d mobile game development: OpenGL ES 2.0 or cocos2d-x?

Tags: java, android, c++, ios, opengl-es

I plan to build a game for mobile. My target platforms are iOS and Android. I hope to be able to carry out testing on windows and/or linux. I'm a bit over my head in this as aside from general game development experience, all the technologies are fairly new to me. I've done a decent amount of research and have concluded that the game should be written in/ported to C++ to ensure that most of my engine can be easily ported to multiple devices.

Another thing I'd prefer is to write the game initially in java and port to C++ since that's where I'm most comfortable and will get it done the fastest.

Now I have the issue of choosing whether to use a game engine such as cocos2d-x, or to write the engine from scratch and use OpenGL ES 2.0 for rendering. Initially I thought it would be better to use cocos2d-x since I don't have a lot of experience with OpenGL. My problem with using cocos2d-x, however, is that since I want to write the game initially in java, that I'm going to have a hard time porting the engine to conform to cocos2d-x (or I'd have to learn all about the cocos2d-x engine to begin with and then write my engine to mimic the cocos2d-x engine.. seems redundant).

Upon further consideration, I thought that writing my own engine using OpenGL would actually be the better option. I'm able to use the PowerVR SDK along with JOGL to emulate a GLES environment. Also it seemed nice since I would be able to allow GL to do most of the work for me in terms of collision detection and transformations. My only issue with this is that since the game is going to have multiplayer support as well, the GL collision detection and such is basically moot since I'm going to have to do collision checking server side anyway to prevent the game from being easily hacked. Of course for the single player game play this method is viable.

Obviously this decision is subjective and depends on my personal preference, though I hope to have given enough background for some more experienced persons to lend their opinions.

That being said, my question is: given these parameters - would it be better for me to use cocos2d-x and suffer the head trauma of building the game from the ground up in C++, or would it be better to write my own engine initially in java and struggle through the OpenGL aspect of it?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/ ?

Comment: I am currently learning OpenGL and I am also working myself into game programming and I can tell you that writing your own game engine is a WHOLE lot of work! I would totally rely on other people's tested and well-optimized work here! If you want to go more into game programming, you could take a look at the UDK, which can compile binaries for all major mobile operating systems with no extra "cost"

Comment: @Till, wow, I'm not sure how that slipped by me.. Thanks, I'll check that out. And thanks for your insight guitarflow.

Comment: I concur with @Creator; developing an engine from scratch is a huge undertaking. Using an engine will let you focus your efforts on the game itself, and not on the framework.  Cocos2D is highly regarded, and a fine choice for your situation as described.  I would however suggest writing it in C++ rather than Java, then you can port rather than rewrite between platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to write it from the ground up in c++ using cocos2d-x. It hasn't been as bad as I expected.

Comment: You're not really writing an engine from scratch if you're using Cocos2d-x, since it in itself is a 2D game engine. If you said you were writing it from scratch using SDL, then that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Building your own engine from scratch would be too much of a work and would attract lot's of bugs to creep into. The tried and tested engines are better choice in my view. The porting would be far more easier to do, since you would be having a working game.
I am using [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com) engine currently and I am quite happy with it's performance. It gives you direct access to the OpenGL libraries, although I've never tried it. You should give it a try too, although it's not free, but the 90 days evaluation license is free to check it out.